# ¿Por qué el thead HTML no funciona en todos los tamaños de papel al imprimir?

Tags: html, css

Estoy usando tablas HTML y necesito que el encabezado se repita en todas las páginas mediante un thead, pero al momento de mandar a imprimir desde el navegador esto no funciona con ningun tamaño de papel, excepto con el tamaño TABLOIDE, donde si se repite el encabezado en cada página. Es necesario que el encabezado funcione en cualquier tamaño de papel, ya que algunos clientes usan uno y otros otro tamaño. El detalle es que el encabezo es bastante grande y sé que tiene un límite, pero si funciona en tabloide, podría funcionar en los demás tamaños de papel. Esto es lo que tengo en el CSS:

```
@media screen {
                thead {display: table-header-group;} 
                div.divFooter {
                    display: none;
                }
            }
            
            @media print {
                thead {display: table-header-group;} 
                table.margen {
                position: fixed;
                top: 0; 
                }
            }

            thead{
                 DISPLAY:table-header-group;
                         max-height: 2500;}
            
            tfoot
                {
                bottom : 0;
                DISPLAY: table-footer-group;
                vertical-align : middle;
                text-align : center;
                bottom: 0;
                }

            .page-header, .page-header-space {
                height: 300px;
                }
            
            .page-header {
                position: fixed;
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya está solucionado. Se hizo un thead anidado. La estructura de la tabla quedaría asi:

Table(Thead, Tbody(Table(Thead, Tbody)))

Para que se repita sin problemas, las filas deben estar bien distribuidas entre los dos thead, ya que el número de filas tambien cuenta, además de la cantidad de px.

En mi caso tenía 11 filas en el primer Thead y 3 filas en el Thead interno, esto hizo que no funcionara en todos los tipos de papel al momento de mandar a imprimir, luego de que se distribuyeran en 7 y 8 filas los Thead quedaron funcionando al 100.

Comment: seria correcto que dejes al menos el código de la estructura de la tabla y el estilo que le aplicaste ... y como llamaste a la funcion para que le dieran el tratamiento adecuado... cualquier cosa pega lo que hiciste y te ayudamos a formatear el codigo...